# List processing to find distances between towns

Tags: list-manipulation

Suppose I have a list that looks like the following  (Town names and total distance to that town)

```
resupply = {
  {"Coleman", 0},
  {"Highwood House", 106},
  {"Canmore", 229},
  {"Exshaw", 245},
  {"Ghost Station", 288},
  {"MountainAire", 370},
  {"Nordegg", 552},
  {"Robb", 672},
  {"Hinton", 720}
  }
```

How would I process that list to give me something like

Coleman - Highwood House   106 km

Highwood House - Canmore   123 km

Canmore - Exshaw            16 km

and so on.

The output gives me the two towns being travelled between, and the distance between them.

Comment: Nice!   Appreciate the quick response...  that helps me a ton.

Comment: If you only knew the most basic functions in Mathematica, you could still do this using a `Table` ... `Table[ fun[ resupply[[i]], resupply[[i+1]] ], {i, 1, Length[resupply]-1}]`.  `Partition` is of course better. My point is that it is usually possible to construct a reasonable solution using only a small, core part of the language.

Comment: Or how about `MapThread[fun, {Most[resupply], Rest[resupply]}]`?  `fun[{name1_, dist1_}, {name2_, dist2_}] := 
 name1 <> " - " <> name2 <> " " <> ToString[dist2 - dist1]` There are countless ways

Comment: from the examples you give, it seems that all towns are linearly connected to a single road or railroad. So you treat it as a 1-dimensional map. Is that the idea?

Comment: @Wouter maybe but not necessarily, the value may be count of km driven today so that e.g. Coleman - Canmore is 229 km but only through Highwood House. There maybe shorter direct path. Or not, depends of OP, I'm just providing alternative.

Comment: Yes,  they are on a linear route  (for a bike packing trip),  interesting to see the other interpretations!

Answer (score 22, accepted):

```
StringTemplate["`1` - `3` <*#4-#2*> km"] @@@  Flatten /@ Partition[resupply, 2, 1]
```

> ```
> {
>  "Coleman - Highwood House 106 km", 
>  "Highwood House - Canmore 123 km", 
>  "Canmore - Exshaw 16 km", 
>  "Exshaw - Ghost Station 43 km", 
>  "Ghost Station - MountainAire 82 km", 
>  "MountainAire - Nordegg 182 km", 
>  "Nordegg - Robb 120 km", "Robb - Hinton 48 km"
> }
> ```

Comment: saves one character: `Partition[Flatten @ resupply, 4, 2]`

Answer (score 7):

```
{place, dist} = Transpose[resupply];
With[{n = Length@resupply}, 
 TableForm[
  Partition[Abs[#1 - #2] & @@@ (dist[[#]] & /@ Tuples[Range[n], 2]), 
   n], TableHeadings -> {place, place}]]
```

[image]

`Outer` could have been used instead of `Tuples`.

Or:

```
pos = Subsets[Range[Length@resupply], {2}];
pairs = #1 <> "-" <> #2 & @@@ (place[[#]] & /@ pos);
d = Abs[#1 - #2] & @@@ (dist[[#]] & /@ pos);
Grid[Transpose[{pairs, d}], Alignment -> Left]
```

[image]

Answer (score 6):

The Terse Way

```
{-#, #2 "km"} & @@@ Differences[resupply] // TraditionalForm
```

$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 \text{Coleman}-\text{Highwood House} & 106 \text{ km} \\
 \text{Highwood House}-\text{Canmore} & 123 \text{ km} \\
 \text{Canmore}-\text{Exshaw} & 16 \text{ km} \\
 \text{Exshaw}-\text{Ghost Station} & 43 \text{ km} \\
 \text{Ghost Station}-\text{MountainAire} & 82 \text{ km} \\
 \text{MountainAire}-\text{Nordegg} & 182 \text{ km} \\
 \text{Nordegg}-\text{Robb} & 120 \text{ km} \\
 \text{Robb}-\text{Hinton} & 48 \text{ km} \\
\end{array}
\right)$

Answer (score 2):

**Using `DistanceMatrix`:**

Formatting/Headings can be looked up from the answer by @ubpdqn.

```
(dm = DistanceMatrix[resupply[[All, 2]]]) // N // Grid
```

[image]

Usage:

```
a = Position[resupply, _?(StringContainsQ["Canmore"])][[1, 1]];
b = Position[resupply, _?(StringContainsQ["Coleman"])][[1, 1]];
dm[[a, b]]
```

> 229

Answer (score 1):

```
vweights = Rule @@@ resupply;

pg = PathGraph[resupply[[All, 1]],
  EdgeWeight -> Quantity[Differences[resupply[[All, 2]]], "km"],
  EdgeLabels -> Placed["EdgeWeight", {1/2 , {1/2, 3/2}}], 
  VertexWeight -> vweights, 
  VertexLabels -> 
    {v_ :> Placed[ {v, v /. vweights}, {Above, Below}, Rotate[#, 90 Degree] &]}
  ImageSize -> Large,
  BaseStyle -> 16]
```

[image]

```
pathlengths = Transpose[{EdgeList @ #, PropertyValue[#, EdgeWeight]}] & @ pg;

Grid[pathlengths, Alignment -> {Left, Center}]
```

[image]

If needed, replace `UndirectedEdge` with `HoldForm @* Subtract`

```
ReplaceAll[UndirectedEdge -> HoldForm @* Subtract] @ %
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Using the (still-undocumented-as-of-version-13.1.0) *six-argument* form of [`Partition`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Partition.html):

```
table = Partition[resupply, 2, 1, {1, -1}, {}, 
   Apply[{HoldForm[# - #3], Quantity[#4 - #2, "km"]} &] @* Join];

Grid[table, Alignment -> {Left, Center}]
```

[image]