# En route to Mobile (driving distances)

Tags: plotting, graphs-and-networks

I want to find a nice way to display driving distances, but got stuck with the following problem:

**1. Example data**

```
vlist = {"Boston" -> 0, "Chicago" -> 80, "Denver" -> 160, 
   "Eugene" -> 40, "Fresno" -> 40, "Gary" -> 50, "Houston" -> 180, 
   "Irvine" -> 120, "Mobile" -> 50};

wlist = {"Boston" -> 0, "Canton" -> 100, "Dayton" -> 220, 
   "Erie" -> 70, "Francfort" -> 40, "Gary" -> 90, "Haggerton" -> 140, 
   "Mobile" -> 200};

vcum = Accumulate @ Values @ vlist;

vvals = Map[Append[1] @* List] @ vcum;

vplot = Transpose[{vvals, Keys @ vlist}] /. {{a_, b_}, c_} :> Callout[{a, 1}, c];

wvals = Map[Append[2] @* List] @ Accumulate @ Values @ wlist;

wplot = Transpose[{wvals, Keys @ wlist}] /. {{a_, b_}, c_} :> Callout[{a, 2}, c];
```

**2. First possibility**

```
ListPlot[{vplot, wplot},
 AspectRatio -> 1/4,
 BaseStyle -> Thickness[0.0015],
 Frame -> True,
 FrameTicks -> {{{1, 2}, None}, {vcum, None}},
 GridLines -> {vcum, None},
 GridLines -> {Automatic, None},
 ImageSize -> 700,
 PlotMarkers -> "OpenMarkers",
 PlotRange -> {All, {0.5, All}},
 Epilog ->
  {{ColorData[97, "ColorList"][[1]], Line[{{0, 1}, {Max @ vvals, 1}}]},
   {ColorData[97, "ColorList"][[2]], Line[{{0, 2}, {Max @ wvals, 2}}]}}
 ]
```

[image]

The advantages of this display form are the scaled distances between towns and the scaling between the two alternate routes. One big disadvantage is that we don't directly see the distance from one town to the next town. With other words: I don't know how to place a label of `160` between `Chicago` and `Denver`.

**2. Second possibilty**

The latter problem is nicely solved in this answer of `kglr`:

[List processing to find distances between towns](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/137306/list-processing-to-find-distances-between-towns/284686#284686)

```
vpath = Thread[Keys @ vlist -> vcum];

PathGraph[vpath[[All, 1]],
 EdgeWeight -> Differences[vpath[[All, 2]]],
 EdgeLabels -> Placed["EdgeWeight", {1/2, {1/2, 3/2}}],
 VertexWeight -> vlist,
 VertexLabels -> {v_ :> Placed[{v, v /. vpath}, {Above, Below}, Rotate[#, 90 Degree] &]},
 ImageSize -> Large,
 BaseStyle -> 10]
```

[image]

The disadvantage here is the missing scaling between the towns. Not being familiar at all with the countless `Graph` display options, I don't know how to overcome this limitation.

**3. Question**

Can we combine the advantages of `ListPlot` (scaling) and `PathGraph` (labeling)?

**4. Note**

The addition of an alternate route is purely optional

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
pathGraph = PathGraph[#[[All, 1]], 
    EdgeWeight -> Differences[#[[All, 2]]], 
    EdgeLabels -> Placed["EdgeWeight", {1/2, {1/2, #4}}, Rotate[#, 90 Degree] &],
    VertexWeight -> Prepend[0] @ Differences[#[[All, 2]]], 
    VertexSize -> Medium, 
    VertexStyle -> #3, 
    EdgeStyle -> Lighter @ #3, 
    VertexLabels ->
        {v_ :> Placed[{v, v /. #}, {Above, Below}, Rotate[#, 90 Degree] &]}, 
    ImageSize -> Large, 
    VertexCoordinates -> Thread[{#[[All, 2]], #2}], 
    BaseStyle -> 14] &;


vpath = Thread[Keys @ vlist -> Accumulate @ Values @ vlist];
wpath = Thread[Keys @ wlist -> Accumulate @ Values @ wlist];

Show[MapApply[pathGraph]@
 {{vpath, 50, Blue, 3/2}, {wpath, 200, Orange, 3/2}}, 
 ImageSize -> 900]
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Using [`GeoGraphics`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/GeoGraphics.html)

```
$Version

(* "13.3.1 for Mac OS X ARM (64-bit) (July 24, 2023)" *)

Clear["Global`*"]

vlist = Entity["City", {#[[1]], #[[2]], "UnitedStates"}] & /@ {{"Boston", 
     "Massachusetts"}, {"Chicago", "Illinois"},
    {"Denver", "Colorado"}, {"Eugene", "Oregon"},
    {"Fresno", "California"}, {"Gary", "Indiana"},
    {"Houston", "Texas"}, {"Irvine", "California"},
    {"Mobile", "Alabama"}};

wlist = Entity["City", {#[[1]], #[[2]], "UnitedStates"}] & /@
   {{"Boston", "Massachusetts"}, {"Canton", "Ohio"},
    {"Dayton", "Ohio"}, {"Erie", "Pennsylvania"},
    {"Frankfort", "Kentucky"}, {"Gary", "Indiana"},
    {"Hagerstown", "Maryland"}, {"Mobile", "Alabama"}};

vpos = GeoPosition /@ vlist;

wpos = GeoPosition /@ wlist;

{vdist, vtour} = FindShortestTour[vpos, vpos[[1]], vpos[[Length[vlist]]]]

(* {Quantity[5316.73, "Miles"], {1, 6, 2, 3, 4, 5, 8, 7, 9}} *)

{wdist, wtour} = FindShortestTour[wpos, wpos[[1]], wpos[[Length[wlist]]]]

(* {Quantity[1908.77, "Miles"], {1, 7, 4, 2, 6, 3, 5, 8}} *)

vdistances = Round[TravelDistanceList[vpos[[vtour]]] // Normal]

(* {Quantity[964, "Miles"], Quantity[30, "Miles"], Quantity[1001, "Miles"], 
 Quantity[1368, "Miles"], Quantity[643, "Miles"], Quantity[263, "Miles"], 
 Quantity[1530, "Miles"], Quantity[465, "Miles"]} *)

wdistances = Round[TravelDistanceList[wpos[[wtour]]] // Normal]

(* {Quantity[457, "Miles"], Quantity[298, "Miles"], Quantity[145, "Miles"], 
 Quantity[359, "Miles"], Quantity[261, "Miles"], Quantity[141, "Miles"], 
 Quantity[659, "Miles"]} *)

Manipulate[
 GeoGraphics[{{Style[Tooltip[Line[#[[1]]], #[[2]]], Thick, Red] & /@
      Transpose[{(TravelDirections /@ (Partition[vpos[[vtour]], 2, 1])),
        vdistances}],
     (Tooltip[GeoMarker[#[[1]], "Color" -> Opacity[0.5, Red]], #[[2]]] & /@ 
       Transpose[{vpos, vlist}])},
    {Style[Tooltip[Line[#[[1]]], #[[2]]], Thick, Blue] & /@
      Transpose[{(TravelDirections /@ (Partition[wpos[[wtour]], 2, 1])),
        wdistances}],
     (Tooltip[GeoMarker[#[[1]], "Color" -> Opacity[0.5, Blue]], #[[2]]] & /@ 
       Transpose[{wpos, wlist}])}}[[list]],
  ImageSize -> Large],
 {{list, {1, 2}}, {1 -> "vlist", 2 -> "wlist"}, ControlType -> TogglerBar},
 SynchronousUpdating -> False,
 TrackedSymbols :> {list}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

```
vv = vlist // Values;
labelpos = {#, 
    1} & /@ (Partition[Accumulate@(vlist // Values), 2, 1] // 
    Map[Mean]);

labels = MapThread[
  Text[Framed[ToString@#1, FrameMargins -> Tiny, Alignment -> Center, 
     RoundingRadius -> 3], #2, {0, 1.2}] &, {Rest@vv, labelpos}];

ListPlot[{vplot, wplot}
 , AspectRatio -> 1/4
 , BaseStyle -> Thickness[0.0015]
 , Frame -> True
 , FrameTicks -> {{{1, 2}, None}, {vcum, None}}
 , GridLines -> {vcum, None}
 , GridLines -> {Automatic, None}
 , ImageSize -> 700
 , PlotMarkers -> "OpenMarkers"
 , PlotRange -> {All, {0.5, All}}
 , ImageSize -> 400
 , Epilog -> {
   {ColorData[97, "ColorList"][[1]], 
    Line[{{0, 1}, {Max@vvals, 1}}]}, {ColorData[97, "ColorList"][[2]],
     Line[{{0, 2}, {Max@wvals, 2}}]}
   (* --- *)
   , labels
   }
 ]
```

[image]

The advantage of this solution is that it preserves the notion of relative distance as opposed to the `PathGraph` which shows the same information as edge weights.